# Text doesn't fit on ONE page - This same text is too large

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, yahoo, bing

Lets say I am describing the text in, for example, 2100 words for the same keyword. My purpose would be to have 700 words per page. Obviously I need to have 3 pages so I can divide the text with, in average, 700 words per page.

The first page (where the text will begin) has doindex attribute, other two have noindex attribute. This way I can protect myself from getting visitors on the website in the middle of the text (second page) or at the end of the text (third page). So I can get visitors always where the text starts and that's why it is doindex.

Obviously, since its the same text but split on 3 parts due its size, I am targeting the same keyword. All 3 URLs will have either exactly the same URL or similar. What do I have to care about so I create preventive solution in advance so I'm not going to have issue with duplication or cannibalization?

What are the list of tasks I need to keep in mind? I have instinct that if I do this, it is very possible I will have duplication issue but don't want that or cannibalizaton. I already know that I should NOT use pagination but rather nofollow internal links from page1 to page2 and from page2 to page3. Anchor text of them should probably be the same - keyword which I'm targeting.

Comment: There's no such thing as "doindex." It's the default behavior, anyway, and nothing needs to be specified for it.

Comment: anyone knows the answer on my question?

Comment: All 3 urls will have the same url? What the hell did I just read?

Answer (score 1):

From this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7737559/250259):

> You can't *force* Google to do anything, however, they have made it
>   easier to deal with pagination issues with a [recent post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/view-all-in-search-results.html) on
>   `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"`.
>
> But the primary problem you face is signalling to Google that your
>   first (main) page is the starting point - this is achieved using
>   internal link and back-link "juice" focussed on that page. You need to
>   ensure that the first page of results is linked to properly from
>   higher-value pages (like the home-page).

and

> Google recently announced that you can use [View All](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/view-all-in-search-results.html) which will
>   allow them to find and index entire articles that are normally broken
>   up using pagination and display them all as one result.

Comment: Thank you for both replies but neither of them has anything to do with my question. I was asking what do I have to do so I protect myself from being "penalized" for either cannibalism and/or duplication due to the reason stated in my first post (same text on more than one page - just because its too large)? If I did some X task, the possibility of duplication / cannibalism might drastically decrease. Now Im looking for that X task what to do...? There might be something more than just 1 task. Pagination and/or internal link to first page has nothing to do with this...

Comment: @Andrew01 I disagree with both your comment and the statement in your OP - "*I already know that I should NOT use pagination*". _This_ is a case for pagination, and it is also _not_ duplicate content (unless your 3 blocks of 700 words are the same)...If that's not the case then you might want to rephrase the question...

Comment: Mike if I used pagination and if I had, in situation mentoined in my first post, some dofollow internal links on second page (second part of same text) and/or third page (third part of same text) then I cannot expect any link juice benefit. But again; pagination doesn't have anything to do with my question. About your sentence "and it is also not duplicate content". So you are saying even if I target the SAME keyword but on different page with different text and even if URL was the same (!!!), I don't need to worry about being penalized for duplication. Correct? What about cannibalism issue?